# SUMPRODUCT Result rounded to Whole Number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I ROUND the result for the following SUMPRODUCT:

```
="Cycle Time"&(SUMPRODUCT((G3:G29)-(B3:B29),--(B3:B29>0),--(G3:G29>0))/SUMPRODUCT((ISNUMBER(G3:G29))*ISNUMBER(B3:B29)))
```

Comment: `="Cycle Time"&ROUND((SUMPRODUCT((G3:G29)-(B3:B29),--(B3:B29>0),--(G3:G29>0))/SUMPRODUCT((ISNUMBER(G3:G29))*ISNUMBER(B3:B29))),[number of digits])`???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the *ROUND()* worksheet function:

```
="Cycle Time"&ROUND((SUMPRODUCT((G3:G29)-(B3:B29),--(B3:B29>0),--(G3:G29>0))/SUMPRODUCT((ISNUMBER(G3:G29))*ISNUMBER(B3:B29))),0)
```